# next.js default loading.js, apply loading.js to child pages

Tags: next.js

Is there a way to add a default loading.js file?
As in, add a loading.js to the app route that applies to all child pages?

I can add a loading.js to a sibling page.js.
But the loading.js does not apply to the other pages under that route segment.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, if you don't mind littering your directory with stub files, is to import from your shared loader.js file and re-export it.

`app/loading.tsx`:

```
export default function LoadingScreen() {
    return <>{/* your loading state here */}</>
}
```

`app/subdir/loading.tsx`

```
import LoadingScreen from "../../loading";

export default LoadingScreen;
```